# I would like to loop this array and Insert the Value Array by Array

Tags: powershell

```
$number = $args[0]

$myarray = &{$h = @{}; foreach ($a in 1..$number) { $h["array$a"] = ""; } return $h; }

Write-Output $myarray

echo ============================================

if ($myarray["array1"] -eq "") {

    $myarray["array1"] = "C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderA\aa.txt" 

    Write-Output $myarray
}

elseif ($myarray["array2"] -eq "") {

    $myarray["array2"] = "C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderB\bb.txt"

    Write-Output $myarray

}


elseif ($myarray["array3"] -eq "") {

    $myarray["array3"] = "C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderC\cc.txt"

    Write-Output $myarray

}

else {

    Write-Output "Array is file exist"
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iASal.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not dealing with arrays at all. Your code is apparently meant to fill a [Hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) with constructed file paths as values.

Why not use a simple for loop to construct this filepath and add to the hash at the same time?

Something like:

```
$number = 4
$myHash = @{}
for ($i = 1; $i -le $number; $i++) {
    # construct a file path and add that as value to the hashtable
    $file = "C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\Folder{0}\{1}{1}.txt" -f [char](64 + $i), [char](96 + $i)
    $myHash["value$i"] = $file
}

$myHash
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                       
value1                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderA\aa.txt                                                                                                              
value3                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderC\cc.txt                                                                                                              
value4                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderD\dd.txt                                                                                                              
value2                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderB\bb.txt
```

Or if you want it ordered (which a Hashtable by definition is not):

```
$number = 4
$myHash = [ordered]@{}
for ($i = 1; $i -le $number; $i++) {
    # construct a file path and add that as value to the hashtable
    $file = "C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\Folder{0}\{1}{1}.txt" -f [char](64 + $i), [char](96 + $i)
    $myHash["value$i"] = $file
}

$myHash
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                       
value1                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderA\aa.txt                                                                                                              
value2                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderB\bb.txt                                                                                                              
value3                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderC\cc.txt                                                                                                              
value4                         C:\myscripts\Powershell_testing\FolderD\dd.txt
```

<sup>`[char](64 + $i)` and `[char](96 + $i)` give you the characters you need. ASCII 65 --> `A` and ASCII 97 --> `a`, and so on.</sup>

Comment: It's not like auto generate of folder Name,, first need to check file exist or not if file is exist I have to insert in this value .. If file doesn't exist loop again and  it's gonna be empty in value  anyway Thank you for your code,, I'm just 2 weeks newbie in Powershell ^_^